# how to send the datatable column through mail in c#

Tags: c#, .net, email

i have two separate functions
one is to fetch the count of the specific column 
another one is to send the mail through c# code 
both worked well
i want to send the count value from data table to body of the mail ?anyone help me?

## program1-to get the count value from data table

```
 public static void push_notify()
        {
            var no = "25/10/2017";

            try
            {
                string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();


                cmd.CommandText = "sampleone";



                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn",no);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(row[x].ToString() + " ");
                    }
                }

                con.Close();


            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

## program 2-send mail in c

```
public static void email_send()
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("someemail@somedomain.com");
                mail.To.Add("somereceiver@somedomain.com");
                mail.Subject = "Hello World";
                mail.Body = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\Users\\vijay\\Downloads\\dancdan.xml"));

                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someemail@somedomain.com", "somepassword");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: It is very insecure to add your email credentials. Please remove your credentials from the question

Comment: If you have both working functions what exactly do you need help with? You only need to add the output you already print to the console to your `mail.Body`!?

Comment: yes how to call that count function in mail body?? @xander

Comment: You could just change the `push_notify()` method to return a string with the value you currently print to the console and then call it from your `email_send()`, that is simple programming basics I'm sure you know that if you can write functions like these.

Comment: You better change your credentials at your employer. In the edit-history, your email credentials are still accesible

Comment: i am new to this plz answer with code sir ..thank you  @xander

Comment: Sorry if you're new I suggest to start learning C# first before you try something like this, SO is not a coding service

Comment: but where to call the string..in message body??@xander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first functions should return the data you want to send by email, something like this:

```
public static List<string> push_notify()
    {
        var no = "25/10/2017";
        var result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();


            cmd.CommandText = "sampleone";



            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn",no);

            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
                {
                    var value = row[x].ToString();
                    Console.Write(value + " ");
                    result.Add(value);
                }
            }

            con.Close();
            return result;

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The second function should call the first one, something like this (assuming they are in the same namespace):

```
public static void email_send()
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        var dataToSend = push_notify();

        mail.From = new MailAddress("someemail@somedomain.com");
        mail.To.Add("somereceiver@somedomain.com");
        mail.Subject = "Hello World";
        mail.Body = string.Join(",", dataToSend);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\Users\\vijay\\Downloads\\dancdan.xml"));

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someemail@somedomain.com", "somepassword");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }

}
```

That should do the trick. However, try to take into account all the advice you are receiving through comments.

Comment: No overload for method 'Join' takes 1 arguments @Tao Gómez Gil it shows error

Comment: @VinothJS I fixed that.

Comment: Thank u so much @Tao Gómez Gil